# How to avoid the dragging after a maximum value in oxyplot?

Tags: .net, wpf, graph, oxyplot

I have a voltage date time graph using oxyplot and what i want is to  avoid the user dragging after the last most point and before the very first point along the X-axis.

I have DateTimeAxis values in x-axis and in y-axis it shows voltage values. 
I do something like this to add points in both the axes:

```
 lineSerie = new LineSeries
 {
    StrokeThickness = 2,
    MarkerSize = 3,
    CanTrackerInterpolatePoints = false,
    Smooth = false,
     LineStyle = LineStyle.Dot,
     Color = OxyColor.FromRgb(66, 134, 244)
  };
  data.ToList().ForEach(d => lineSerie.Points.Add(new DataPoint(DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(d.Time), Convert.ToDouble(d.Tesnion))));
 PlotModel.Series.Add(lineSerie);
```

How can i avoid the dragging after the minDate and MaxDate ?(Lets say minDate contains the leftmost point and maxDate contains the rightmost point in X-Axis).

Answer (score 2):

You can specify `AbsoluteMinimum` and `AbsoluteMaximum` on your Axis. From the [source](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/OxyPlot/Axes/Axis.cs):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the absolute maximum. This is only used for the UI control. 
    /// It will not be possible to zoom/pan beyond this limit. 
    /// The default value is <c>double.MaxValue</c>.
    /// </summary>
    public double AbsoluteMaximum { get; set; }
```